# Add Dynamic value to input field inside a table in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a dynamic row table where all the table cells are input fields.
There is some preloaded data, but I am not able to add to the loaded data in the view. However add/ delete rows are working properly. I have tried ngModel and value but it's not working.

**app.component.html:**

```
    <table>
            <thead>
                <button (click)="onAddRow()" *ngIf="addForm.get('rows')">add row</button>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of addForm.get('rows')?.controls;let index = index;">
          <!-- NOT WORKING with ngModel
          <td>name : <input [ngModel]="row.get('name')" [formControl]="row.get('name')"></td> -->
            <!-- NOT WORKING with value attribute
          <td>name : <input value="row.get('name')" [formControl]="row.get('name')">\</td> -->
          <td>
            name : <input  [formControl]="row.get('name')">
          </td>
          <td>
            description : <input [formControl]="row.get('description')">
          </td>
          <td>
            qty : <input [formControl]="row.get('qty')">
          </td>
          <td>
            <button (click)="onRemoveRow(index)">Remove</button>
          </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray, NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  addForm: FormGroup;
  rows: FormArray;
  itemForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      items: [null, Validators.required],
      items_value: ['no', Validators.required]
    });
    this.rows = this.fb.array([{
    "name": "Test Item",
    "description": "Dedsc",
    "qty": "q23"
  }]);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm.get("items").valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if (val === true) {
        this.addForm.get("items_value").setValue("yes");

        this.addForm.addControl('rows', this.rows);
      }
      if (val === false) {
        this.addForm.get("items_value").setValue("no");
        this.addForm.removeControl('rows');
      }
    });
  }

  onAddRow() {
    this.rows.push(this.createItemFormGroup());
  }

  onRemoveRow(rowIndex:number){
    this.rows.removeAt(rowIndex);
  }

  createItemFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: null,
      description: null,
      qty: null
    });
  }

}
```

My output:
[image: Current output]

Expected output:
[image: Expected Output]

Also putting one [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-5k7zbe) for better reference.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `[ngModel]` because you already working with reactive forms. These inputs are empty because you create each item form group with `null` values. If you have preloaded data you need to pass it as initial value for each control in `createItemFormGroup` method or update the value by methods `setValue/patchValue` of form array or appropriate form group.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if that will be exactly what you want, but check this one out:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-k2lbkw

- i replaced the formControl attribute with formControlName. Note the **value** property

```
<td>
     name : <input  formControlName="name" 
                   [ngModel]="row.get('name').value" >
</td>
```

- added the name, description, qty to the form builder object.

```
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.addForm = this.fb.group({
          items: [null, Validators.required],
          items_value: ['no', Validators.required],
          name: [null, Validators.required],
          description: [null, Validators.required],
          qty: [null, Validators.required]
        });
        this.rows = this.fb.array([]);
      }
```

- and added some dummy values on the createItemFormGroup method

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The solution is fine, but just in case I have some previous values or an array of items inside the ```rows``` (formbuilder array), How do I use it?

The functionality I require is I would load few data and list them in table and additionally people can add/ remove rows. On final submit, I will pass the rows array to API for update in backend.

Comment: I followed this example (https://ng-run.com/edit/BmjgZeJJqYSPfbDDh5Kq?layout=1) and was able to achieve what I wanted. But I am curious about what was the issue in the first place (as in my question).